# Gmail APIでGmailクライアントを作るときの認証方法

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail, .net-core

C#・dot net core 3.1です。

GmailAPIを使ってメールクライアントのように、

1. アカウント追加ボタンを押す
2. Googleログイン画面が開く
3. 権限を許可
4. 以後は許可を促すプロンプトを出さずに使用できる

の流れを作りたいのですが、方法がわかりません。

GoogleのAPI管理サイト（GoogleCloudPlatform）でOauth2認証情報を作成し、Jsonをダウンロードしました。
そのJsonをつかって以下のようにOauth2認証でTokenを取得できました。Tokenを保存した以後は許可を促すプロンプトは表示されずに使えました。

```
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly};
        static string OAuthCredentialFilePath = "Credentials/credentials.json";

        private static async Task OAuth2Auth()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(OAuthCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true));
            }

            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });
        }
```

おそらくメールクライアントのようにGmailアカウントを新たに追加するというのは、ユーザーにGoogleアカウントでログインさせて新たにTokenを取得して保存するということだと思います。
しかし、この場合だと新たに認証することができません。

メールクライアントのようにアカウントを追加していくフローを実現するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/302928

Comment: 必要な機能/APIと `GMail API`という言葉は違うものなのでは？ [組織の作成と管理 | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization?hl=ja), [ユーザーの追加方法 - Google Workspace 管理者 ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/179832?hl=ja), [新規ユーザーのアカウントを追加する - Cloud Identity ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/33310?hl=ja), [Gmail API Overview | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides)

Comment: 私のレベルでは理解が及ばないので、差し支えなければもう少し詳しくお願いできますでしょうか。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 私も知っている訳ではありません。ただ`GMail API`は1ユーザーがその権限の範囲内(自分のメールボックスだけ)で使うAPIであって`GMailクライアントを作る`ことは出来ないのでは？と考えているわけです。それが出来るのは、Googleが組織等に対して提供しているサービス/APIを契約した`管理者が使用するAPI`とそれを使う管理者でしょう。なので質問のタイトルとか使っている言葉の対象とするものを見直した方が良いと思ってコメントしました。ただし内容を知っているわけでは無いので回答するまでのことは出来ません。

Comment: たとえばWindows10やmacOSにプリインストールされているメールアプリのようなもの（これらは実際にはIMAPを使用しているようですが）を作りたいという話ですよね、であれば指摘されているその点は問題ない、あるいは的はずれなような気がします。もっとも、細かい話をすればこの文脈でのAuthは認証ではなく認可とツッコまれるかもしれませんが。

Comment: ああ、そういう質問であれば私の方が誤解でしたね。Google側のサービスのアカウントを作成するものと間違えていました。済みません。検索するとPythonでの最近の記事とC#のちょっと古い記事があるようで参考になるかも。[Python を使い、Gmail API 経由で Gmail の送受信を行う](https://qiita.com/muuuuuwa/items/822c6cffedb9b3c27e21), [Gmail APIを使ってメール送信するC#コード](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=11612)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

みなさんありがとうございます。
複数アカウントを追加していくことはできました。
GoogleからOAuth2で使用するjsonをダウンロードする際にはもちろんGoogleアカウントが必要ですが、私はそのアカウントでダウンロードしたJsonファイルではそのアカウントでしか使用できないと勘違いしていました。

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true));
```

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync`というメソッドのuserという引数を変えると、新しい認可画面が表示されました。
これで違うアカウントでログインしてスコープを許可すれば、`FileDataStore`でしていしたディレクトリにアクセストークンが保存され、以後user引数に渡したユーザー名でトークン保存先のディレクトリを見に行ってくれるようです。